# Ag grid server side pagination not working

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to implement server side pagination using angular agGrid. When setting the dataSource, I hardcoded rowCount to -1 with an expectation of ag grid displaying **1 to 10 of more** and  **Page 1 of more.** .The browser is, however, displaying **1 to 10 of 10** and  **Page 1 of 1.**.

[Current behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh5jM.png)

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTrSB.png)

[Here is how the dataSource is set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYVXO.png)

[Hear is how the template is set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Fy1.jpg)

Comment: Did u fix it?I have same issue in Vue!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved and these were changes that were made:

1. Added the following gridOptions

   ```
    this.gridOptions.serverSideSortOnServer = true;
    this.gridOptions.serverSideFilterOnServer = true;
    this.gridOptions.rowModelType = 'serverSide';
    this.gridOptions.serverSideInfiniteScroll = true;
   ```
2. Set cachedBlockSize to pageSize

   ```
    <ag-grid-angular
        class="ag-theme-density zebra"
        [columnDefs]="translatedColumnDefs"
        [cacheBlockSize]="pageSize"
        ...(more grid Options)
    </ag-grid-angular>
   ```
3. Changed success to the following

   ```
    params.success({
        rowData: rows,
        rowCount: rows.length < pageSize ? pageSize + rows.length : -1,
    });
   ```